# Display JSON Response data in recycler view in Kotlin

Tags: json, rest, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Trying to display the JSON data in recycler view (Kotlin). I'm not getting any error.
Given permissions in manifest as well.

API consuming

**Base URL**
`http://106.51.52.207:8092/hrdome/`

**API**

```
@GET("locations/getAll/24")
    suspend fun getAllLocations(): List<LocData>
```

**Below is our JSON data**

> {"status":true,"statusCode":200,"statusMessage":"ok","errorMessage":null,"data":[{"id":37,"state":null,"country":null,"address1":null,"zipCode":null,"headOffice":false,"address2":null,"city":null,"locationName":"holi","deleted":false,"organizationId":24,"organizationName":"JPMC"},{"id":38,"state":"AndhraPradesh","country":"India","address1":"MVP","zipCode":"530034","headOffice":false,"address2":null,"city":"Pune","locationName":"MVP office","deleted":false,"organizationId":24,"organizationName":"JPMC"},{"id":81,"state":"testing","country":"testing","address1":"testing","zipCode":"555555","headOffice":false,"address2":"8/55/102","city":"testing","locationName":"testing","deleted":true,"organizationId":24,"organizationName":"JPMC"},{"id":89,"state":"bhihar","country":"india","address1":"8-134","zipCode":"566666","headOffice":false,"address2":"ramnagar","city":"bhihar","locationName":"ramnagar office","deleted":false,"organizationId":24,"organizationName":"JPMC"}]

Trying to display the "data": in to Recycler View

**Main Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var locationRepository: LocationRepository
    private lateinit var locationViewModelFactory: LocationViewModelFactory
    private lateinit var locationViewModel: LocationViewModel
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var postAdapter: LocationAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initRecyclerView()

        locationRepository = LocationRepository()
        locationViewModelFactory = LocationViewModelFactory(locationRepository)
        locationViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this, locationViewModelFactory).get(LocationViewModel::class.java)

        locationViewModel.getPost()

        locationViewModel.myResponse.observe(this) {
            postAdapter.setLocationData(it as ArrayList<LocData>)
            it[1].locationId.let { it1 -> Log.d("main", it1) }
            it[2].country.let { it2 -> Log.d("main", it2) }
            it[3].name.let { it3 -> Log.d("main", it3) }
            it[4].address1.let { it4 -> Log.d("main", it4) }
            it[5].headOffice.let { it5 -> Log.d("main", it5) }
            it[6].address2.let { it6 -> Log.d("main", it6) }
            it[7].zipCode.let { it7 -> Log.d("main", it7) }
            it[8].city.let { it8 -> Log.d("main", it8) }
            it[9].deleted.let { it9 -> Log.d("main", it9) }
            it[10].organizationName.let { it10 -> Log.d("main", it10) }
            it[11].organizationId.let { it11 -> Log.d("main", it11) }


            recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        postAdapter = LocationAdapter(ArrayList())
        recyclerView.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            adapter = postAdapter
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
class LocationAdapter(private var locationList: ArrayList<LocData>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationAdapter.LocationViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LocationViewHolder =
        LocationViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_list, parent, false)
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LocationViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val location=locationList[position]
        holder.id.text = location.id.toString()
        holder.locName.text=location.name.toString()
        holder.address1.text = location.address1.toString()
        holder.address2.text=location.address2.toString()
        holder.city.text = location.city.toString()
        holder.state.text= location.state
        holder.country.text = location.country.toString()
        holder.zipCode.text=location.zipCode.toString()
        holder.headOffice.text = location.headOffice.toString()
        holder.deleted.text=location.deleted.toString()
        holder.orgName.text = location.organizationName.toString()
        holder.orgId.text=location.organizationId.toString()
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = locationList.size

    class LocationViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        val id: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewid)
        val locName: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewlocationName)
        val address1: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewaddress1)
        val address2: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewaddress2)
        val city: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewcity)
        val state: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewstate)
        val country: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewcountry)
        val zipCode: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewzipCode)
        val headOffice: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewheadOffice)
        val deleted: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewdeleted)
        val orgName: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textVieworganizationName)
        val orgId: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textVieworganizationId)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setLocationData(locationList: ArrayList<LocData>)
    {
        this.locationList=locationList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

**Base URL**

`const val url="https://106.51.52.207:8092/hrdome/"`

**Data Class**

```
data class LocData (
    val id: String,
    val locationId: String,
    val country: String,
    val name: String,
    val address1: String,
    val headOffice: String,
    val address2: String,
    val zipCode: String,
    val city: String,
    val deleted: String,
    val organizationName: String,
    val organizationId: String,
    val state: String
)
```

**API**

```
 @GET("locations/getAll/24")
    suspend fun getAllLocations(): List<LocData>
```